# Sound crash when playing with Oboe

Tags: android, latency, oboe

All my code works fine. I can load and play all my sound.
I load 200 sound with a player array for play one of them all or more at same time.
But I have a last problem. Now when I play a sound, the quality is very bad sometimes or if I spam it, it really bad like robot. 
I need to create an app like a DJ sound tab. 
With a lot of sound I can spam with buttons. I'm using RythmGame Sample. But maybe my problem is I need to more custom the mixer or something like that. Can someone help me with that please ?

Comment: I'm trying to use FFMpeg without resampling my files for a new test

Comment: If it is robot sound then maybe the number of channels is not being handled correctly in the callback. Maybe you are only filling half the buffer.

Comment: Have you figured this out yet?  Perhaps a code sample might give us a better idea of what we're working with.  How are you setting up your audio stream, are your audio files encoded to a 48000 sample rate at 16-bit PCM for raw files, etc.  Just from reading your description, I wonder if trying to mix together 200 audio samples at the same time is slowing you down?  Try running a systrace and see what is taking up most of your time.